# Vector equation with scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $x,y,z$ be $n$-dimensional vectors.

if $x$ and $y$ are known, is there any way to solve this equation for $z$?

$$x^\top y =x^\top z$$

I know that the equation can be rewritten as

$$\|y\|\cos(\theta) = \|z\|\cos(\lambda),$$

where $\theta$ and $\lambda$ are the angles between $x$ and $y$, $z$ respectively. So I can find a solution in terms of $\|z\|$, but is there any way to find a more explicit solution in terms of the vector $z$?

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions for $z$ provided $x$ and $y$ are non-perpendicular and non-zero. The equation you have found should be enough to verify this. This is true provided $n > 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation

$$x^\top y =x^\top z$$ is equivalent to

$$x^\top (y-z) = 0$$ which means that $y-z$ is orthogonal to $x$. So let $H$ be the hyperplane orthogonal to $x$  (providing $x \neq 0$). $z$ is a solution of the equation if and only if it belongs to the set $y + H$.

Comment: aren't there infinite number of planes orthogonal to x?

Comment: No. In a vector space endowed with an inner product, the orthogonal to a non-zero vector is uniquely defined.

Comment: @Apprentice Note that the hyperplane orthogonal to a vector in an $n$ dimensional space is $n-1$ dimensional so in that sense there can be infinitely many planes in that space if say, $n=4$ so that the hyperplane is three dimensional but the hyperplane is uniquely defined. You can ask yourself what the kernel and image of the map $\varphi (y) = x^Ty$ are for more clarity as to why this is the case.